# Easiest way to do endless scrolling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, will-paginate

Have tried most of the tutorials and blog on endless scrolling with rails but none seems to work for me what is the easiest way to implement a load more or endless scrolling with rails

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a Rails questions and more of a Javascript question. You will need to detect when the user has reached the bottom of the page and fire off an Ajax request to an endpoint that you can either have return JSON data or just HTML.

Here is a tutorial, it's the best I can offer you without seeing code: http://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/

Answer (score 1):

People often see infinite scroll as this complex being. The truth of the matter, is that infinite scroll is just pagination. There are several key players in the rails pagination game, I'm pretty fond of [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). All we are doing is loading the first page and then detecting when we have reached the bottom of the content loaded on the first page, then sending a request to our server to fetch the next page, and appending those results to the end of our existing results.

Fortunately for you, Kaminari has an entire, easy to follow, tutorial on building infinite scroll with their gem.